# Calculate between dates under certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count days between two or more identical codename cells. What I need is shown right below in the `daysBetween` column:

```
codename    date         daysBetween
AAA         20-oct-2011  NaN
AAB         20-oct-2011  NaN    
AAB         21-oct-2011  1
AAB         29-oct-2011  9
AAB         21-oct-2012  365
```

---

Below was my raw data:

```
codename    date         daysBetween
AAB         21-oct-2011  NaN
AAO         20-oct-2011  NaN
AAB         21-oct-2012  NaN
AAB         20-oct-2011  NaN     
AAB         29-0ct-2011  NaN
```

I managed to first sort the data by `codename` and `date` using

```
file.sort_values(by=['codename', 'date'])
```

Result:

```
codename    date         daysBetween
AAA         20-oct-2011  NaN
AAB         20-oct-2011  NaN    
AAB         21-oct-2011  NaN
AAB         29-0ct-2011  NaN
AAB         21-oct-2012  NaN
```

Here came my problem, when cells in `codename` are identical I needed to calculate days between the first date compared to other dates.

I think I need to use pandas `Timedelta(date1 - date2).days`, but exactly how I find identical cells in `codename` and them compare the first date to the rest of the dates I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.sort_values(by=['codename', 'date'])

df['new'] = (df['date'] - df.groupby('codename')['date'].transform('first')).dt.days
print (df)
  codename       date  daysBetween  new
0      AAA 2011-10-20          NaN    0
1      AAB 2011-10-20          NaN    0
2      AAB 2011-10-21          1.0    1
3      AAB 2011-10-29          9.0    9
4      AAB 2012-10-21        365.0  367
```

**Explanation**:

Aftr converting to datetimes and sorting use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for get `Series` with same size like original DataFrame, so is possible subtract, last convert timedeltas to [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html).

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('codename')['date'].transform('first'))
0   2011-10-20
1   2011-10-20
2   2011-10-20
3   2011-10-20
4   2011-10-20
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked excellent.

I saw you used .diff() before, now you're using .transform('first'). I guess .transform compares to the first?

Comment: @jubibanna - Exactly, give me a sec for explanation.